# GitHub Actions strategy matrix equivalent in CircleCI

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, github-actions, circleci

as the title describes, is there an equivalent of [GitHub Actions Strategy matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix) in CircleCI?

Maybe I'm just blind and couldn't find it. As far as I've seen there's only [this](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/parallelism-faster-jobs/) which just talks about test parallelization.

If not, is there a way to avoid writing this over and over just with a different `parameter` each time in my workflow?

```
- upgrade:
    param: param1

- upgrade:
    param: param2

- upgrade:
    param: param3
```

Really feels like there should be a way avoid calling the same job with just with a different param over and over...

Comment: Unlike GitHub Actions, CircleCI supports [anchors and aliases](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/writing-yaml/#anchors-and-aliases) in YAML, so you can DRY some things up with that (see e.g. [this config](https://github.com/textbook/fauxauth/blob/63a98b6ec82d7221522139464c990d72bf28f16b/.circleci/config.yml#L141-L154) I wrote that runs the same steps in three different image versions). Beyond that, there's [`matrix`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#matrix-requires-version-21)

Comment: @jonrsharpe matrix was what I was searching for, thank you!! Do you want to add an answer rather than a comment I can choose as a solution?